# Angular 5 Socket.IO Chat not updating

Tags: angular, socket.io, angular5

I'm making a site with Angular 5 with a real time chat.
It's working for the user sending messages, but the other clients won't get the new message without refreshing.
Backend is NodeJS, which is all working fine, same as the sockets.
The chat not refreshing is the problem here.

chat.component.ts:

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { Socket } from 'ng-socket-io';
    import { ChatService } from '../services/chat.service';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-chat',
      templateUrl: './chat.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./chat.component.css'],
      providers : [ChatService]
    })

    export class ChatComponent {

      messages: string[] = [];

      constructor(private socket: Socket, private chatservice: ChatService) {
        this.socket.on('getOldChat', (data) => {
          this.messages.push(data);
        });
      }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.chatservice.onMessage()
        .subscribe((message: string) => {
          console.log('Pushing new msg: '+message);
          this.messages.push(message);
        });
      }

      sendChat(chatmessage) {
        if (!chatmessage) {
          console.log('Blank Message!');
          return;
        }
        console.log('Sending new message: ' + chatmessage);
        this.socket.emit('sendChat', chatmessage);
      }
    }
```

chat.component.html:
`<div *ngFor="let message of messages"><li class="chatmessage">{{ message }}</li></div>`

chat.service.ts:

```
        import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
        import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
        import { Observer } from 'rxjs/Observer';
        import { Socket } from 'ng-socket-io';

        @Injectable()
        export class ChatService {

          constructor(private socket: Socket) { }

            public onMessage(): Observable<string> {
                return new Observable<string>(observer => {
                    this.socket.on('getChat', (data: string) => observer.next(data));
                });
            }

        }
```

Comment: add observer.complete() after you emit data to it.

Comment: That's not the problem, the problem is that only the sender sees the new msg, the other users connected have to refresh.

Comment: I already figured it out, In my server I didn't add io.sockets.emit to send it to all sockets!